# python retrieve text from multiple random wikipedia pages

Tags: python, python-2.7, wikipedia, wikimedia

I am using python 2.7 with wikipedia package to retrieve the text from multiple random wikipedia pages as explained in the [docs](https://wikipedia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code.html#api).

I use the following code

```
def get_random_pages_summary(pages = 0):
    import wikipedia
    page_names = [wikipedia.random(1) for i in range(pages)]
    return [[p,wikipedia.page(p).summary] for p in page_names]

text =  get_random_pages_summary(50)
```

and get the following error

> File
>   "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py",
>   line 393, in __load raise DisambiguationError(getattr(self, 'title',
>   page['title']), may_refer_to)
>   wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError: "Priuralsky" may refer to:
>   Priuralsky District Priuralsky (rural locality)

what i am trying to do is to get the text. from random pages in Wikipedia, and I need it to be just regular text, without any markdown

I assume that the problem is getting a random name that has more than one option when searching for a Wikipedia page. 
when i use it to get one Wikipedia page. it works well.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the document(http://wikipedia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) the error will return multiple page candidates so you need to search that candidate again.

```
try:
    wikipedia.summary("Priuralsky")
except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
    for page_name in e.options:
        print(page_name)
        print(wikipedia.page(page_name).summary)
```

You can improve your code like this.

```
import wikipedia

def get_page_sumarries(page_name):
    try:
        return [[page_name, wikipedia.page(page_name).summary]]
    except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
        return [[p, wikipedia.page(p).summary] for p in e.options]

def get_random_pages_summary(pages=0):
    ret = []
    page_names = [wikipedia.random(1) for i in range(pages)]
    for p in page_names:
        for page_summary in get_page_sumarries(p):
            ret.append(page_summary)
    return  ret

text = get_random_pages_summary(50)
```

Comment: i am still getting an error - 
line 393, in __load
    raise DisambiguationError(getattr(self, 'title', page['title']), may_refer_to)
wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError: "Churn" may refer to: Butter churn
Churning (butter)
Milk churn
Churn drill
Chuck Churn
River Churn
Churn Creek
Churn Creek Protected Area
Devils Churn
Churn railway station
Churn (Shihad album)
Churn (Seven Mary Three album)
Churn (band)
Product churning
Churning (stock trade)
Churn rate
Churning (cipher)

Comment: found it! the problem with your code was that sometimes when finding more than one option and searching for it yields more than one option also, i solved it with running the get_page_summary function again over each option in e.options

Comment: I fixed my code. Anyway, it was good that you could solve it.

Comment: thanks! I found something else now, the problem is that when getting more than one value, and looking for all the values for each value, it becomes recursive, and again giving more than one solution including the one that we had before e.g sometimes you get many repetitions of the same Wikipedia value

Answer (score 4):

As you're doing it for random articles and with a Wikipedia API (not directly pulling the HTML with different tools) my suggestion would be to catch the DisambiguationError and re-random article in case this happens.

```
def random_page():
   random = wikipedia.random(1)
   try:
       result = wikipedia.page(random).summary
   except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
       result = random_page()
   return result
```